# Listing error on overleaf

Tags: listings

I have copied below code in my source file. Code does not appear in proper format(as it is). All text mix up (without any gap). No caption at the bottom. Getting error message "environment 1stlisting not defined". Plz guide me how i can correct it? I am adding list between two lines.

```
Used variable (n,m) are critical and are used by anothere functionas described in below listing. 
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=Python example]
import numpy as np
    
def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
    m = len(genl1)
    n = len(genl2)
    M = None #to become the incidence matrix
    VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int) dummy variable
     compute the bitwise xor matrix
    M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)
    M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1) 

    for i in range(m-1):
        for j in range(i+1, m):
            [r,c] = np.where(M2 == M1[i,j])
            for k in range(len(r)):
                VT[(i)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(i)*n + c[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + c[k]] = 1;
                
                if M is None:
                    M = np.copy(VT)
                else:
                    M = np.concatenate((M, VT), 1)
                
                VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)
    
    return M
\end{lstlisting}

Now VT value is assigned to fictorial function for mathematical calculations.
```

Text appears as

Used variable (n,m) are critical and are used by anothere functionas described in below listing.
language=Python, caption=Python example] import numpy as np def incmatrix(genl1,genl2): m = len(genl1)
n = len(genl2) M = None #to become the incidence matrix VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int) dummy variable
compute the bitwise xor matrix  M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1)
for i in range(m-1):for j in range(i+1, m):
[r,c] = np.where(M2 == M1[i,j]) for k in range(len(r)): VT[(i)*n + r[k]] = 1; VT[(i)*n + c[k]] = 1; VT[(j)*n + r[k]] = 1;VT[(j)*n + c[k]] = 1;
if M is None: M = np.copy(VT) else: M = np.concatenate((M, VT), 1) VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)
return M.
Now VT value is assigned to fictorial function for mathematical calculations.

Comment: Welcome to TeX;SE! Please extend your code snippet to complete small document (MWE: Minimal Working Example), which reproduce your problem and which we can test as it is. BTW, overleaf is just editor and have nothing with your problem,

Comment: `"environment 1stlisting not defined". ` means in your document you used  `1stlisting ` with **1** not `lstlisting ` with **l**

Comment: I have replaced 1 with I,but no effect. I have copied answer given in post(How to force listing inside acolumn in overleaf. Same problem occur with this code also. I have also use break line command but useless. Is it necessary to add start document and end document command before listing? Currently, i am adding listing between a paragraph.

Comment: please make an example document that shows your problem

Comment: Example is the text copied from post (reference above). Line break is still not working.

Comment: with error message"environment listing not defined.

Comment: you have not provided any code we can run or referenced any other code

Comment: Welcome @pianke // You'll have less problem and much less discussion once you provide code which: a) starts at `documentclass`, b) ends at `end{document}`, c) is as short as possible, d) compiles, e) AND still shows your problem. I.e. we can copy, compile and improve it without guessworking.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided a test document showing an error. The `lslisting` shown will not produce the error mentioned, and produces this output

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Python, caption=Python example]
import numpy as np
    
def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
    m = len(genl1)
    n = len(genl2)
    M = None #to become the incidence matrix
    VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int) dummy variable
     compute the bitwise xor matrix
    M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)
    M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1) 

    for i in range(m-1):
        for j in range(i+1, m):
            [r,c] = np.where(M2 == M1[i,j])
            for k in range(len(r)):
                VT[(i)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(i)*n + c[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + r[k]] = 1;
                VT[(j)*n + c[k]] = 1;
                
                if M is None:
                    M = np.copy(VT)
                else:
                    M = np.concatenate((M, VT), 1)
                
                VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)
    
    return M
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. Now it look properly. But all other text above and below listing is not appearing. I can see list content only . I have message "show document preamble".

Comment: Now want to see the content above and below the listing  and generate the pdf of whole document. I tried it by removing start & end document command but in that case it give error and pdf is generated.

Comment: @pianke this is why you were asked to provide an example document. I have no idea what your problem is. It seems to be unrelated to any code you have shown.

Comment: [language=Python, caption=Python example] import numpy as np def incmatrix(genl1,genl2): m = len(genl1) n = len(genl2) M = None to become.....
 1; VT[(i)*n + c[k]] = 1; VT[(j)*n + r[k]] = 1; VT[(j)*n + c[k]] = 1;
.....M=np.concatenate((M, VT), 1) VT = np.zeros((n*m,1). Text appear as above(with no line break,all text adjacent to each other). Now i copied the code from your reply post, it appear in proper format but line above the listing is not appearing with all other contents of the file.